# happened vs it happened

Tags: tense, verbs, exam-questions

I got confused with this question.

> The train may be late, as ……… yesterday.
>
> A. happened
>   B.  it happened
>   C.  happening
>   D.  it was happened

Option B sounds correct and natural to me, in fact the correct option is A.

Could somebody tell me the reason?

Answer (score 2):

> The train may be late, as happened yesterday

Here, the second clause is dependent on the first, as indicated by the comma.

Adding 'it':

> The train may be late, as it happened yesterday

implies that is not the case, i.e. the 'it' is referring to the train - trains don't 'happen', and so this sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The correct is the first one, why?

Because if you add **it** to the sentence is like if you think **train happened**, thats make not sense; meanwhile if you think **happened** refers to the train arriving late to the station